# How to create topic in firebase cloud messaging

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to create a topic in the Firebase cloud messaging using java spring boot but I don't know how to create it. I want to send a message to all the users who subscribe to the topic but I don't know how to create a topic in FCM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no separate operation to create a topic. Topics are automatically creates when a user first subscribes to them, or when a first message is sent to them.